# JSoup - Select only one listobject

Tags: java, parsing, selector, jsoup

I'm trying to extract some certain data from a website using JSoup and Java. So far I've been successful in what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<ul class="beverageFacts">
<li><span>Årgång</span><strong>**2009**&nbsp;</strong></li>
```

I want to extract what is inside the ** in the above HTML. I can do this by using the code that follows in JSoup:

```
doc.select("ul.beverageFacts li:lt(1) strong");
```

I'm using the lt(1) because there are several more list items following that I want to omit.

Now to my problem; there's an optional information tab on the site I'm extracting data from, and it also has a class called "beverageFacts". My code will at the moment extract that data too, which I don't want it to do.

The code is further down in the source of the website, and I've tried to use the indexer :lt(1) here aswell, but it wont work.

```
<div id="beverageMoreFacts" style="display: block">
<ul class="beverageFacts"><li class="half">
<span> Färg</span><strong> Ljusgul färg.</strong>
```

My overall result is that I extract "2009 Ljusgul färg." instead of only "2009". How can I write my code so it will only extract the first part, which it succesfully does, and omits the rest?

EDIT:
I get the same result using:

```
 doc.select("ul.beverageFacts li:eq(0) strong");
```

Thanks,
Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are qualifying only one part, whereas you should qualify both. Try this:

```
doc.select("ul.beverageFacts:eq(0) li:eq(0) strong");
```

What you are saying is: give me the first list item of each list of beverages. What you need to say instead is: Give me the first item of the first list of beverages.

Comment: Alright, I've tried that now and it makes sense! Though, that returns the wrong list item, and omits the one I am after!

I took pasted the source here: http://pastebin.com/5muzFQ7i

The information I want is on line 308, while the information that gets extracted is on line 435. Shouldn't the first one in the source be of index 0?

Thanks alot for helping me out! =)